# ASP.NET Core MVC App on Linux - Raspberry Pi Not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, nginx, raspberry-pi

I got an ASP .Net MVC WebApp running on raspberry Pi, with NGINX Server. 
It's a blank project, the default MVC project.

I got it deployed and accessible via the network. However, it does not display correctly either on the Pi or accessing via from my Laptop.

It does display correctly when I run it from the Debug in my VS.
Running on Debug from VS:
[image: SP]
Same app running "Dotnet App.dll" from Linux:
[image]
I was wondering if I am missing something on the Program.cs or Startup.cs, or if I am publishing it wrong.

Publish Options: File / Release / netcore3.1 / Framework-Dependent / Portable (Tried Linux-arm - same)

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000");
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

App Install Folder in the Linux: 
[image]

Comment: How did you run it on Linux? Reveal that please. Very likely you didn't launch the application from the folder it resides, so that it cannot locate those style files and so on.

Comment: Hi @LexLi. I have open terminal cd to the folder it is installed, and run the command "don't WebApplication8.dll". Added a picture above.

Comment: Hmm, I think is something with NGINX configuration. So if I run it locally it does show the pages properly. When I go through NGINX (remote) the pages do not show correctly... I am not using HTTPS in either of the cases

Comment: Okay, I am noob...but this was very bad..When publish there is a folder called "wwwroot" as part of the package, the NGINX needs to point to there... You gave me a valuable lead @LexLi, it was pointing to the wrong files.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, NGINX Files were pointing to the wrong directory. The problem was the configuration of "sites-enabled" location, not pointing to where the HTML lives.

More info see the NGINX Docs or the LINK:
[Tutorial ASP.NET CORE - PI](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-core-application-with-mysql-server-using-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-the-web-server)

Solved!