# Webside run on Raspberry pi but don't displaying correctly .NET CORE MVC

Tags: linux, model-view-controller, raspberry-pi, asp.net-core-mvc

I have problem similar to this
[asp-net-core-mvc-app-on-linux-raspberry-pi-not-displaying-correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860824/asp-net-core-mvc-app-on-linux-raspberry-pi-not-displaying-correctly)

except that my site doesn't display correctly even after typing localhost:5001 into the browser on Raspberry.
The application was published directly on Raspberry.
When I publish the application on the desktop version of Debian the site works fine. The page displays the same way using different browsers.